# Vim: Using an external command and handling errors

Tags: shell, vim

I am trying to use an external command to handle some formatting over a range of lines in Vim but can't seem to find a way to deal with errors from the external command.

These errors are usually when the shell returns something other than 0 and it prompts Vim to display something along the lines of:

```
shell returned 1
```

Besides doing that, it replaces the lines I wanted to format with the actual message of the error. This happens as well if I do:

```
:set equalprg=myformatter\ --format-flag\
```

How can I safely catch an error for an external command and display whatever the error message is?

Note: this is *not* a question on how to *use* an external command to format some text in Vim, but rather, how to catch an error and display the message back.

Comment: I'd also like to know this! In particular trying to create a command that runs tidyall (https://metacpan.org/module/tidyall) on the vim buffer. If an error occurs, I want to display the error, rather than replacing the buffer with the error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but I got this rough draft working (see further below for equalprg). It basically remaps `gq`, overwriting it to print the error and then undo it.

```
set formatprg=~/test.sh

nnoremap gq :setl opfunc=FormatPrg<cr>g@
fun! FormatPrg(...)
   silent exe "'[,']!".&formatprg
   if v:shell_error == 1
      let format_error = join(getline(line("'["), line("']")), "\n")
      undo
      echo format_error
   end
endfun
```

This is what's in `~/test.sh`:

```
echo "error!!
alskdjf alskdf
alskdj flaskdjf" 1>&2
exit 1
```

### Edit:

I just realized that I didn't answer your question at all haha. My solution for `equalprg` is even less elegant, but it may suit your needs. To use this **you must set equalprg**. Either comment out the nnoremap line or `set indentexpr=EqualPrg()` if you want to switch back and forth between an external tool and the internal indentation formatter.

```
set equalprg=~/test.sh    

nnoremap = :setl opfunc=EqualPrg<cr>g@
fun! EqualPrg(...)
   if &equalprg != ""
      silent exe "'[,']!".&equalprg
   else
      set indentexpr=
      exe "norm! `[=`]"
      set indentexpr=EqualPrg()
   endif
   if v:shell_error == 1
      let format_error = join(getline(line("'["), line("']")), "\n")
      undo
      echo format_error
   endif
endfun
```

Comment: You should not `shellescape()` equalprg here: it is passed to shell as-is (your variant is not going to work with `set equalprg=myformatter\ --format-flag` mentioned in the question). More, you should not just `shellescape()` anything you path to any bang (`!`, `read !`, `w !` and so on): use `shellescape(str, 1)`: with a second non-zero argument.